# How to turn list into data frame after list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code and I was wondering how do I properly turn it into a data frame with country as one column and population as the other after looping through my function with list comprehension?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

countries = ['af', 'ax']

def get_data(countries):
    url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/'+countries+'.html'
    page = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    # geography
    country = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'region'}).text
    population = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'field-population'}).find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)
    dataframe = [country, population]
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame([dataframe])
    return dataframe
results = [get_data(p) for p in countries]
```

What I tried and it gives me the following data frame:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(results)

                                      0                                       1
0   0 Afghanistan Name: 0, dtype: object    0 Afghanistan Name: 0, dtype: object
1   0 Akrotiri Name: 0, dtype: object       0 Akrotiri Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: unrelated to the problem: naming a variable as a keyword looks HMMM - talking about dataframe variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you're returning it as a DataFrame from `get_data()`. If you return it as a dictionary, it will be much more logical for conversion to a dataframe later.

```
countries = ['af', 'ax']

def get_data(countries):
    url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/'+countries+'.html'
    page = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    # geography
    country = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'region'}).text
    population = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'field-population'}).find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)
    scraped = {'country':country, 'population':population}

    return scraped
results = [get_data(p) for p in countries]
```

This returns a list of dictionaries such as:

```
[{'country': 'Afghanistan', 'population': '36,643,815'},
 {'country': 'Akrotiri',
  'population': 'approximately 15,500 on the Sovereign Base Areas of Akrotiri and Dhekelia including 9,700 Cypriots and 5,800 Service and UK-based contract personnel and dependents'}]
```

So when you convert with `pd.DataFrame(results)` you get:

```
       country                                         population
0  Afghanistan                                         36,643,815
1     Akrotiri  approximately 15,500 on the Sovereign Base Are...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [136]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
     ...: import html
     ...: from urllib.request import urlopen
     ...: import pandas as pd
     ...:
     ...: countries = ['af', 'ax']
     ...:
     ...: def get_data(countries):
     ...:     url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/'+countries+'.html'
     ...:     page = urlopen(url)
     ...:     soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
     ...:     # geography
     ...:     country = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'region'}).text
     ...:     population = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'field-population'}).find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)
     ...:     json_str = {"country":country, "population":population}
     ...:     return json_str
     ...: results = [get_data(p) for p in countries]
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(results)

In [137]: df
Out[137]:
       country                                         population
0  Afghanistan                                         36,643,815
1     Akrotiri  approximately 15,500 on the Sovereign Base Are...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your original function as:

```
def get_data(countries):
    url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/'+countries+'.html'
    page = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    # geography
    country = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'region'}).text
    population = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'field-population'}).find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)
    return country, population
```

and call

```
results = [get_data(p) for p in countries]
```

as you suggested, you can do something like this:

```
def listToFrame(res, column_labels=None):
    C = len(res[0]) # number of columns
    if column_labels is None:
        column_labels = list(range(C))
    dct = {}
    for c in range(C):
        col = []
        for r in range(len(res)):
            col.append(res[r][c])
        dct[column_labels[c]] = col
    return pd.DataFrame(dct)

df = listToFrame(results)
```

or, even nicer,

```
df = listToFrame(results, ['Country', 'Population'])
```